# EF6 DbContext lifecycle issue

Tags: entity-framework

I've decided to architect my solution without repositories and unit of work (given that EF is itself a repository/uow so why abstract an abstraction). So I have a Service/Business Logic layer which will call EF directly. My service has a number of methods (Create, Update, Delete) which call _context.SaveChanges() and I am injecting the DbContext in the constructor.

However if I call multiple methods using the same service instance and one fails, all further service methods will also fail. For example

```
var svc = new PersonService();
var person = new Person{ Name = "Angie" };
svc.Create(person);
svc.Delete(56); //delete person with Id 50
```

Lets assume Create throws an exception on SaveChanges for some reason. When I call Delete, there is still a faulty Person object in my context, so when Delete method calls SaveChanges it will throw the same exception.

Of course I can get around this by always instantiating a new PersonService in my calling code but this just screams WRONG.

This leads me to using a new context for each service method, which will mean method injection instead of constructor injection which I was hoping to avoid.

I've considered going back to repository/uow but it seems that this just moves the problem one layer deeper.

Is method injection of my context the right way to go or am I missing something here?

Thanks